# Loading either Camera or Gallery through phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

I've got an area where I want two buttons that load either the camera and upload a pic or loads the gallery then uploads the pic. This is a phonegap application.

This works:
**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" onclick="takep()"><img src="icons/camera-icon.png" /></a>
```

**JS:**

```
function takep(SessionKey, PetID) {
    // Retrieve image file location from specified source
    navigator.camera.getPicture(
        uploadPhoto,
        function(message) { alert('get picture failed'); },
        {
            quality         : 50,
            destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType      : navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
        }
    );
}

function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
    $.mobile.loading( 'show', { theme: "b", text: "Loading", textonly: false})
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";


    var params = {};
    var Username = localStorage.getItem("Username");
    var SessionKey = localStorage.getItem("SessionID");
    var PetID =  localStorage.getItem("addPetID");
    var callback = "moo0";

    params.Username = Username;
    params.SessionKey = SessionKey;
    params.AnimalKey = PetID;
    params.Filename = "moo";
    params.callback = callback;
    console.log(Username);
    console.log(SessionKey);
    console.log(PetID);



    options.params = params;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://redacted/UploadFileCollection"), win, fail, options);

}
```

However, both of these buttons don't load anything:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" onclick="capturePhotoWithData()" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">From Camera</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="capturePhotoWithFile()"  class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b">From File</a>
```

**JS:**

```
function capturePhotoWithData() {
    // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
    navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, onFail, { quality: 50 });
}

function capturePhotoWithFile() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, onFail, { quality: 50, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to a media example on phonegap:

It is from a phonegap employee:

https://github.com/ismael-jimoh/Media-FilePath

You are probably not including cordova.js with your package... which is why it doesn't work.